# Notify Author when Question is migrated

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, notifications

I have accounts on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User.  Today I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/68989/building-a-wsus-server-where-to-start-closed) on Super User that was [migrated](https://serverfault.com/questions/83600/building-a-wsus-server-where-to-start) to Server Fault.

I was never notified that my question had been migrated.

When something important happens (a new answer is posted, an answer is voted upon, etc) the envelope icon next to the username turns a different color.  Clicking on this icon reveals Recent Activity.

There was never a notification that my question had been migrated, and no `Recent Activity` showed up.

I just happened to be browsing ServerFault and found a question with the exact same title as mine, and found that my question had been migrated.

#### Feature Request

> **Please notify users when their question is migrated**, preferably on
> both sites.

Comment: Good idea to get the notification on both sites.

Comment: +1 Very good idea! Maybe this would improve things; right now, there are quite a few questions where the author doesn't even have an account on the site it's been migrated to.

Comment: This would be especially useful for new users how might additionally be offered a link to the faq "What is this migrated question thing about?". Which I actually can't find, only faq on *how* to migrate...

Comment: I guess this is `[status-completed]` as per [the December 2010 top bar notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73274/reputation-loss-when-a-question-is-transferred/73282#73282)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Great suggestion. The question owner is now notified via in-site messaging when their questions are migrated to another site.

[image: Migration notification on top of the screen]

Comment: In-site messaging == topbar notification, right? (Like shown [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73274/reputation-loss-when-a-question-is-transferred/73282#73282).) Or has this been changed to use [private messages](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/moderator-messages/)? (Like shown [here](http://i.imgur.com/Jy35Z.png).)

Comment: @arjan topbar notification

Comment: [But shouldn’t you care about your question more than any other human being on the planet? If it is migrated, you should already know about that without needing a special magic notification.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94400/255554) </sarcasm>

Answer (score 14):

I think a user should be notified for all close reasons.  It could show up under the revisions tab, or they could create a new tab for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not against this feature request, but is it really necessary?  If you actually care about your question, you'll eventually go back to it to read the answers that have been posted.  Once you arrive, you should see the conspicuous "this question has been migrated to" box on it.

Comment: Why do we even have notifications then? We notify people when they get new answers, and hopefully that's the one thing they're definitely checking for