# User doesn't get notification when one of their questions is migrated

Tags: feature-request, migration, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify Author when Question is migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/notify-author-when-question-is-migrated)

When a user's question is migrated to another site nothing shows in the recent activity, not even on the revisions page.  Also, I *think* that no notification shows up in the notification bar (but I'm not 100% sure since it hasn't happened to me recently).  If the migration doesn't happen very soon after the question is asked, the user might not even realize that there has been any activity.

I think that there should be some kind of notification to the user, at least a red-envelope notification.

Comment: See "Notify Author when Question is migrated" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/notify-author-when-question-is-migrated

Comment: @ArjanvanBentem: thanks, didn't see that when i searched before asking