# Notifications on migrated question

Tags: feature-request, migration, notifications

While we're still waiting for [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/notify-author-when-question-is-migrated) to be fixed, I have another question/feature-request that is pursuant to the last:

After a question gets migrated, let's say to a site the the OP is *not* registered on - will he still get notifications on any answers to his question? I assume not.  Now the problem is, he wasn't notified that the question moved, and now he doesn't know that he's actually getting good answers to his question on another site.

It's a shame, really... waste of good answers there.

So the feature request (assuming the above is correct). Either:

- Fix the previous [FQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/notify-author-when-question-is-migrated)
- Notify the user from the original site, on answers to his question on the target site (I assume there is still some correlation between users there?)

Comment: I like the second bullet; it seems like it should be possible to show alerts in the user's inbox, even if they've never been to the target site

Comment: Does this still happen now that cross site notifications are a thing?