# Notify users who answered when question is migrated

Tags: feature-request, bounties, migration, accepted-answer, notifications

On the same line of thinking as: [Notify Author when Question is migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/notify-author-when-question-is-migrated/79450#79450) I think it would be helpful for users whose answer were either accepted, or awarded a bounty (maybe even over a certain number of votes) to receive a notification that the question has been migrated.

Some users will spend a fair amount of time researching an answer and going back to edit as new information becomes available. It seems only fair to be able to see where this time has ended up.

I recently noticed a 400 rep drop and assumed the question was deleted and the information I posted lost. After asking in meta ( [I've lost a lot of rep when the question with my answer has disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81721/losing-rep-for-deleted-questions) ) I discovered it was simply migrated and I had no way of knowing.

**Feature Request**

> Please notify users who had an accepted answer or were awarded a bounty if the question was migrated.

Comment: I have to think that this should be [feature-complete] -- I get these notifications nearly daily. And it's annoying. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not like to get notifications for questions that I have posted an answer for (accepted or not).  I understand how someone who asked a question would need to know.  But after I leave an answer I don't normally need to come back to it.  The few times that I might need to and that it happened to be migrated, would not be worth the notifications for the all the othere times that I don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

I got a notification today that a question I'd answered had been migrated to dba.

[pg_restore fails for a pg_dump from a db that worked just fine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12875/1064)

But my answer, which I *think* the OP accepted, didn't migrate with the question. I just answered it again.