# Alert Answerers when a Question gets Migrated

Tags: feature-request, migration, recent-activity, alerts

Recently I lost a lot of rep on SO because one of my top answers was migrated to another site.  At the time, I thought the question had been deleted.

I was pleasantly surprised (weeks later) when I joined the other Stack Exchange site and found I already had a bunch of rep on it.  It made me stop to wonder if any of my other answers had been migrated.

It would be nice if users could be alerted whenever one of their answers gets migrated.  Each migration could show up in the user's activity feed, or there could be a page summarizing all their migrated answers.

I would feel much more motivated to participate on other Stack Exchange sites if I knew I already had answered a few questions on it.

Comment: A more narrow version of this: [applying only to bounties and accepted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81738/notify-users-who-answered-when-question-is-migrated).

Answer (score 4):

A notification when your post -- either question or answer -- has been migrated would be very helpful.  (I *think* askers get a notification, but I'm not certain.)  Most of the time, from what I've seen, content that was written for one site needs some adjustment when migrated to another -- the sites' baseline assumptions are different, rules about questions and answers are different, even what constitutes acceptable sources might be different.  So it's bad enough that you lost the answer on the site where you wrote it, but for all you know it might be getting downvoted over on the other site for these kinds of reasons.  Wouldn't you want to know that?  I sure would.