# Notify all involved users when migrating a question

Tags: feature-request, migration, notifications

There was a similar [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81738/156722) on this, but it only covered users who had answered the question, but not users who flagged it or commented on it.

I find it quite aggravating when I comment on a post, and then I come back to look at it again, and I have no Idea where it went. I try searching for it on a site it might have been migrated to, but I still am unable to find it.

I think it would be nice to either notify all users involved in a post when and to where it is migrated, or, (even better) in the user page, keep the link to the answer (or comment if you're looking in "activity") there, and just have it forward wherever the question has been migrated to. (or both)

In addition (This may require a separate question, but I'm not sure. Let me know about this one) It would also be nice to be notified whenever a flag is found helpful.

---

Edit: As per the comments below, I realize that it would be best to be opt-in (per-question), so that users who don't want it, don't have to be notified.

---

Thoughts?

Comment: +1, but make this opt-in.

Comment: -1 and you better make this opt-in if you decide to build it.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast I edited it to make it opt-in, what's the -1 for?

Comment: Probably because he [disagrees with your proposed feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Answer (score 3):

> I find it quite aggravating when I comment on a post to have it migrated, and then I come back to look at it again, and I have no Idea where it went. I try searching for it on the site that I suggested it be migrated to, but I still am unable to find it.

Please stop doing that. Seriously. I mean it. Stop.

It's not you personally I have a problem with, but 99% the "hmmm, this belongs on Foo Stack Exchange" comments are just plain wrong. If you feel the question would be more suitable for another site, vote to migrate / flag (whichever applies).

And if you really want to check if the question was migrated, just favourite it.

> In addition (This may require a separate question, but I'm not sure. Let me know about this one) It would also be nice to be notified whenever a flag is found helpful.

You can just check your profile every couple of days and see if your flags were marked helpful or not. Why would you need a notification for that? Notifications are horribly annoying, you just haven't got enough of them yet, it won't be long before you realize just how annoying they are.

Comment: It's not just comments about migrating the question, but it could be a comment of any kind. It would still be nice to be able to know where the question went. I haven't tried favoriting one, but it is documented in your activity when you comment on something, but the link only seems to go to a 404 page.

Comment: @Ephraim Ah, then it was deleted. Not much you can do there...

Comment: Yes, not only are this "would be better on *x* site" comments usually wrong, but they tend to encourage people to re-post their question on another site, which creates a duplicate if the suggestion is valid and the question ever does get migrated there.