# How do I add a comment to a Stack Overflow answer?

Tags: support, comments

I am a brand new member.  I saw an answer, but I had a question and I can not figure out how to post a comment on, question or an answer.

I can see where I can share the answer and I can edit the answer.  But I do not see how I can post a question.

Answer (score 3):

You get yourself a reputation of 50 then you can comment.

Answer (score 2):

[See the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

> All users may leave comments on their own posts and any answers given
>   to their own questions. Users with at least 50 reputation may comment
>   on any post. (There is no reputation requirement to post comments on
>   MSO.)

once you completed 50 reputation you would see `add comment` option below the post like:

> [image: add comment]