# Migrated question of non-existing user

Tags: discussion, feature-request, linked-accounts, migrated-questions

I just replied to [a post which was migrated from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177979/how-do-i-add-a-comment-to-a-stack-overflow-answer):

> [image: migrated]

There is no user info on the question. This might be because the user does not have an account linked on Meta.

So, if a question is migrated and the user does not have an account on that particular site, does the user get the notifications for answers or comments?

If not, I think the user should be notified.

Answer (score 2):

When this site moves to Meta Stack Exchange, and Stack Overflow gets a shiny new Meta of its own, this will be less of a problem. Questions like this will be migrated to the new Meta Stack Overflow, where SO users *will* have accounts, because the accounts on main and meta are linked.

However, the general question remains a good one.

> Are users notified of actions on their migrated posts when they have no account on the target site?

I think the answer is no, but I wouldn’t swear to it. And you’re right: they should be.