# How do you pick the question in here to answer?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers

I think this is great platform and I do get answers to what I post. I however am confused about how do I start contributing by answering some of the questions. I am wondering how people find out the questions that they think they can answer. Do you keep going through all the questions? Are there any filters which says I am basic/moderate/advanced user in some topics?

Comment: Answer the ones you know solutions to. Also this isn't a programming question, please read the FAQ for this 'great platform' http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use the **Favorite Tags** and **Ignored Tags** feature on the SO front page to make sure you see only questions you feel qualified to answer.

Don't try to answer questions unless you're sure about the answer.

Comment: I didn't realize this thread was moved to meta and was surprised to see it, when I logged in meta to ask another question.

Comment: @ManishSapariya I've always wondered about that, did you get no notification at all that your post had been migrated?

Comment: @ManishSapariya This [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/notify-author-when-question-is-migrated/79450#79450) suggests you should have recieved a notification when your post was migrated, bug?

Comment: @RichardTingle may be I missed notification and did notice it for long. I don't think its a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I just look at the front page and see what's there. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can look for questions in areas you're good at.
Click on a tag in the "Unanswered Tags" list in the right side of the screen in https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=5&tab=newest

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what pavium has suggested, I subscribe to the RSS feed of the tags. It helps me keep my interaction within my Email client, which have RSS reader.