# Where is my question?

Tags: support, migration, specific-question

Once I gave one good question about writing a good PHP+HTML code. I gave a bounty, and one guy answered saying that the question was very nice, with very long description. Now, I can't find the question.

Did anybody transfer it, or even delete it? How can that happen without I am informed about it?

Comment: I would double check [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/237681/hey)

Comment: [This is a list of your bounty questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/237681/hey?tab=bounties#page_1-bsort_offered) . Not there?

Comment: @Martin Smith: No, it's not there, I had checked that before. I can't believe this...

Comment: Was it [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80136/what-is-good-neat-architecture-in-programming)?

Comment: Yikes. If this can happen by design, something is seriously wrong with the design.

Comment: @Tim Stone: Thank you very much! I can't believe I didn't have notification or something about migrating. I think those questions could still stay in StackOverflow and be redirected when clicked. Thank you again.

Comment: @Tom: They do stay on Stack Overflow for a month.

Comment: @Jeremy This one was killed after 6 days for some reason

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question you were looking for was [migrated to Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80136/what-is-good-neat-architecture-in-programming) (and then deleted on Stack Overflow). You actually should have been [notified of the migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/notify-author-when-question-is-migrated/79450#79450) when it happened, although having never experienced this I don't know how reliable the notification is. It's possible too that you just forgot about receiving the notification, since the migration happened several months ago.

Comment: The notification should happen as a banner at the top of the screen. Not sure if it ever expires or what happens when the original question is deleted, though.